# jQuery Ajax Object abort method does not really cancel the Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, abort

I'm trying to preload some files with ajax requests

```
var foo = $.ajax({url:'http://blahblah.com/myfile.jpg'});
```

But, when I call `foo.abort();` the developer tool's Net Panel (in FireFox and Network in Chrome) shows that the file is still downloading, and will stop download if stop page loading by browser or use `window.stop()` method.
Are there any ways to stop download, too?